# PHP: get random images from 5 Folders

Tags: php, image

I have 5 folders and each folder contains 50 images.

I want to display only 10 random images from 5 folders.

I tried the following code to display the images, but it is displaying the all the images from only the `Tel` Folder, but I want to display the random images from 5 folders.

```
<?php
$handle = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).'/Tel/');

while($file = readdir($handle)){

  if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..'){
    print_r($file);
    echo '<img src="Tel/'.$file.'" border="0"  width="100" height="100"/>';
  }
}
```

Comment: Read the contents of the folders into an array then select 10 random entries from the array.

Comment: [`array_rand()`](http://au2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) will help you here.

Answer (score 0):

```
$img_array = glob(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).'/Tel/'.'*.{jpg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
```

For Another dir

```
array_merge($img_array, glob(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).'/Tel/1'.'*.{jpg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
.
.
.
array_merge($img_array, glob(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).'/Tel/5'.'*.{jpg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
```

For rendom 5 `images`

```
// this function provide you 5 random keys of `$imgArr`
$rand_keys = array_rand($img_array, 5);
```

Than, proceed this way

```
foreach($rand_keys as $key){
    // $img_array[$key];  is file directory path, convert into `HTTP` path.

    $file_data = pathinfo($img_array[$key];); 
    //file name with extension $file_data['basename']; 
    // $dir_path get directory fetch as per your dir path   
    echo '<img src="'. $dir_path. $file_data['basename'].'" border="0"  width="100" height="100"/>';
}
```

Comment: Not getting images from different directory..   getting following warning: Warning: array_rand(): Second argument has to be between 1 and the number of elements in the array in

Comment: `$directory_1` or `$directory_2` should be correct path. you have ask in question.
 **I want to display only 10 random images from 5 folders.**

Comment: yes that is my question     $directory_1 = '/Tel/';

$directory_2 = '/2/';

$directory_3 = '/3/';

$directory_4 = '/4/';

$directory_5 = '/5/';  this is the path for 5 diretoriies

Comment: @JackTorris, i have updated code, try this way and please try `echo` OR `var_dump` to each step to debug code..., hope you would get it

Comment: @JackTorris the answer code process will according your requirement, i am not sure about `dir` path so you should resolve own base.. good luck